# Img onerror validating with html5 form

Tags: javascript, html, image, required

I have added a form to my HTML file. And it works fine. When I try to submit the required field should be filled in. The next step is the following: I want an image link in my input fields for adding a profile image from source. I also let this work as well.

I also built a constraint which check if the image is valid. If it isn't valid it shows only a placeholder image.

I've used this small function for that:

```
prevAvatar.onerror = function () { this.src = "images/placeholder.jpg"; };
```

The next step is to display a message to the user to show that his given image is not a image.

I was wondering if it is possible to write some code that shows the same error as an empty field does for HTML5 REQUIRED fields.

Does anyone have a smart solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No I do this for a school project, they said it is not allowed:(

Comment: you can use input.setCustomValidity() to mimic or improve the UX output of html5 validation attribs